# Error: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12 setRequestHeader@[native code]

Tags: angularjs, iphone, http-headers

I am in the process of developing a mobile application for Android and IOS, with Phonegap and AngularJS, CORS_REST. I have just about everything working for the headers on Android. When testing on an iPhone with GapDebug.

Here is an example of the authentication code:

```
$http.post('someurlhere', {username: username, password: password})
                        .then(function (response) {
                            if(!response.IsAuthenticated) {
                            alertsManager.addAlert('Username or password is incorrect', 'alert-danger');
                        }
           callback(response);
                         console.log(response);
        });
```

I am getting this a an error:

[SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12_IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CQjL.jpg)

If anyone could please help I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank You:

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please, check your headers params, iOS9 does not accept parameters in the http headers that has space at the beginning of the value. Example:

"Token":" Token12345" => wrong
"Token":"Token12345" => correct

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Would this be on the server side?

Comment: Great catch! In case it's useful for someone else: I think a trailing space also causes this error. For example including a header like this:
"Authorization: Bearer "

Comment: @hookdump had this same error, that fixed it for me!

Comment: Fixed a problem for me in Safari on OSX as well.